# What is more efficient {X:Static Class.Default} or {StaticResource Class}?

Tags: xaml

Suppose I have class I want to reference in XAML.

```
public class MyConverter
{
  public static readonly MyConverter Default = new MyConverter();
  ...
};
```

And then in XAML I can reference it either

```
<Label Content="{Binding Text,Converter={x:Static local:MyConverter.Default}"/>
```

or

```
<local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
...
<Label Content="{Binding Text,Converter={StaticResource local:MyConverter}"/>
```

Which way is more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt anything here will be more effecient than other but the key difference here is what is actually going on:

1. In first approach you're referencing static field of class `MyConverter`
2. In second case you're creating an **instance** of `MyConverter` and using it.

I believe first one might couple percents faster (or what do you mean by efficient?) but this difference won't give you much profit. I would choose option #1 if you already have a static field. Also as far as I remember `x:Static` still is not available in Silverlight.

Comment: The question was more of a theoretical nature, since there are more than one way to skin the cat. Of course in day to day the performance would not matter much, but I found x:Static a little bit more convenient, because you don't have to declare resource.

Answer (score 1):

I find the first option interesting as it provides a nice and clean possibility to use the class for different variations of a task in combination with a singleton. Imagine a visiblity value converter like this:

```
public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly VisibilityConverter defaultInstance = new VisibilityConverter();

    public static VisibilityConverter Default = new VisibilityConverter();
    public static VisibilityConverter InverseBoolean = new VisibilityConverter() { Inverse = true };

        public bool Inverse { get; set; }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var isVisible = value != null
                && value.GetType() == typeof(bool)
                && (bool)value;

            if (Inverse)
            {
                isVisible = !isVisible;
            }

            return isVisible ? System.Windows.Visibility.Visible : System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
```

This can then easily be used in a default and in a inverse mode:

```
Converter={x:Static converters:VisibilityConverter.Default}
Converter={x:Static converters:VisibilityConverter.InverseBoolean}
```